# Is a triangle with two equal angles always isosceles?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

An isosceles triangle is a triangle with two sides that are equal in length. This means that two angle will also be equal to each other. Is there any way that a triangle could have two equal angles, but not be an isosceles triangle?

Comment: The law of sines is the easiest way to see this.

Answer (score 2):

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with $\angle BCA=\angle ABC$. Then observe that $ABC\equiv ACB$ (the order of the vertices is important), because they satisfy $ASA$ criterion. Therefore, we have that $CA=AB$, i.e. $ABC$ is isosceles.